# Replace only "functor" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to replace only the "functor" function of a JavaScript object. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
// PART 1: Declaration
function obj() {
    return obj.a + " " + obj.b; 
};
obj.a = "a"; 
obj.b = "b"; 
confirm(obj()); // output: "a b"; 

// PART 2: Modification
// now replace only functor 
// (not working this way as it replaces the whole object)
obj = function () {
    return obj.b + " " + obj.a; 
};
confirm(obj()); // expected output: "b a";
```

I need this because I don't have access to PART 1 and need to modify the object's function...

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

Copying (e.g. with a for-loop) is not working as it does not copy all hidden attributes...

**UPDATE:** Modified code that it is not undefined...

**UPDATE2:** This seem to work for this example: (requires jQuery)

```
obj = $.extend(function() { return obj.b + " " + obj.a; }, obj);
confirm(obj()); // output: "b a";
```

(However it didn't solve my problem...)

Comment: For all browser , it is undefined undefined

Comment: There is no Javascript object, just a function. `a` and `b` are properties of the function, there's no object that contains them.

Comment: Could you post the "for-loop" code you tried?

Comment: Ok, and how can i change only the function body of the function object?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686389/overriding-a-function-without-removing-static-properties

Comment: I'm confused as to why commenters would say "you can't set variables on a function like that". A function is just like any other object in some senses, including the ability to set properties on it. Anyway, in what way did copying the properties onto the new function not solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an object and a function referring to each other, and then you only change the function part of it.

```js
var obj = function() {
    var x = function() {return x.f();}; 
    x.f = function() { return x.a + " " + x.b; };
    return x;
}();

obj.a = "a";
obj.b = "b";

alert(obj());
```

To change the function, just change obj.f:

```
obj.f = function () {
    return obj.b + " " + obj.a; //swap the order.
};

alert(obj());
```

**EDIT:** Missed the part where you said that you don't have access to Part1, so this solution won't work for you, but have left this here in case it helps someone else, and because it allows you to use obj() directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert your function / object. That is make an object and put a function inside it. This will mean that in order to call the function you will need to specify the object thus :

```
obj = {
  functor : function () {
    return this.a + " " + this.b; 
  }
};
obj.a = "a"; 
obj.b = "b"; 
confirm (obj.functor ()); // output: "a b"; 

// PART 2: Modification
// now replace only functor 
obj.functor = function () {
    return this.b + " " + this.a; 
};
confirm (obj.functor()); // expected output: "b a";
```

Comment: This will not work as the client of the object obj will call obj() and I can't change that...

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap it like this (paste this code into Chrome's console):

```
// PART 1 - exactly as provided

function obj() {
    return obj.a + " " + obj.b; 
};
obj.a = "a"; 
obj.b = "b"; 
console.log(obj()); // output: "a b";

// PART 2 - object is used in different context

var API = {
    setObj: function(obj) {
        this._obj = obj;
    },
    useObj: function() {
        console.log("API: " + this._obj());
    }
}

API.setObj(obj);
API.useObj();

// PART 3 - wrapping obj, changing it's default behavior

objWrapper = function(obj) {

    var wrappedObj = function() {
        return wrappedObj.b + " " + wrappedObj.a;
    }

    var i;
    for(i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            wrappedObj[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }

    return wrappedObj;
}
obj = objWrapper(obj);
console.log(obj()); // expected output: "b a";
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.b);
obj.c = "c";
console.log(obj.c);

// PART 4 - checking different context

API.setObj(obj);
API.useObj();
```

This is the only way you can make it work. You will have to update every reference to this function, so if you can't simulate `API.setObj(obj);` then you can't make it work. You can't redefine only body of a function. Maybe in the future they will add it, as it could be really helpful indeed, and it will make JS more functional programming language.

I replaced `confirm` dialogs into `console.log` as it was annoying!;)

Hope it will help!

Comment: I don't think this will work as I need all properties on the outer object (as other classes expect them to be there...)

Comment: You're passing `obj` to objWrapper. This way you will not lose a reference to this object. You can easily play with this code to even return this reference's properties whenever needed!

Comment: If you don't overwrite `obj` variable then no. If you overwrite it, then yes, but you can rewrite properties. Can you use `wrappedObj` for your purposes and leave `obj` untouched?

Comment: No this is not possible as the object is used by KnockoutJS and the framework expects the whole object, I only want to modify its function, nothing else (your solution will not work)

Comment: Hey @RicoSuter - I've changed my answer. I was researching as it's very interesting problem. And it proves that JS is not fully functional programming language.